# How can I add a listener to an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

I have a directive that builds a Google chart.  I would like to trigger an event handler on my controller's scope when the directive receives an event from the chart.

Sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/yn4KuQfrYvlQNbPSWk3Q?p=preview

in my markup:

```
<div column-chart="chartData" row-selected="rowSelected(index)"></div>
```

in my directive:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    console.log('directive#select', chart.getSelection());
    // call the function defined in the markup for "row-selected"
});
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.rowSelected = function (index) {
    console.log('controller#rowSelected', index);
    // the function I want to ultimately be called
};
```

Can I do this with 1 directive?  Can the chart directive know about the row-selected directive?  Any help you be great, thanks.

Comment: As a follow up, it is possible to do as requested using scope and "&" and "=".  I will do some poking and understand how it works and hopefully update this with an answer.

Comment: Here is the working revision: http://plnkr.co/edit/3C5xNqaWOWTNtQLZpmx6?p=preview . This was the result of looking at this repo: https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart . I am switching to using his directive instead, but this process gave me better insight into directives so time well spent.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have code that is outside of angular scope that you want to change scope with, you need to tell angular by using `$apply`. This will run a digest cycle with he updated scope

So using the event listener in chart can do:

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.rowSelected=chart.getSelection()
     })

 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/osPD4vreoLdOeWZ2kykh?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I had it this way, just modifying the scope directly and using apply, but it felt strange.  I shouldn't be using an attribute for the function to my controller?

Comment: attribute for what? Not exactly sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Not just working directly with the scope, but using an attribute in the markup to define an event handler.

Comment: event handler to do what? Not being very concise

Comment: As originally stated: "I would like to trigger an event handler on my controller's scope when the directive receives an event from the chart."  Not being very nice.

Comment: you don't have isolated scope so you can use controller methods in directive ...`scope.$apply(function(){
          var firstFirstSelletedRow=chart.getSelection()[0]
          scope.rowSelected(firstFirstSelletedRow)
        })` Controller and directive have same scope

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the scope function rowSelected

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  console.log('directive#select', chart.getSelection());
  scope.rowSelected(chart.getSelection().row)
});
```

If you want to not hard-code *rowSelected* you could pass it in via the attributes to make it more flexible.